# Unable to upload images to S3 from Scrapy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scrapy

My spider works fine if I use local file to store the downloaded images.

But when trying to upload to Amazon S3, it shows this error

```
    2018-02-24 14:37:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'category': {'level_1': {'name': u'Electronics', 'url': u'electronics'},
                  'level_2': {'name': u'Accessories',
                              'url': u'electronics-computers-office-accessories'}},
     'image_urls': [u'http://www.some.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/165x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/s/rs500.jpg'],
},
     'name': u'Gift Card Rupees 500',
}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/scraper/scraper/pipelines.py", line 32, in process_item
        if not item['images']:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 59, in __getitem__
        return self._values[key]
    KeyError: 'images'
```

I have below settings for AWS

```
IMAGES_STORE = 's3://myproject-products-images/'
IMAGES_EXPIRES = 180
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'sdfasfasfsaf'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'adfasfasfasf'
```

I have a fresh s3 account all default settings.

Here is my pipeline to check for images which is throwing the above error

```
class ImageCheckPipeline(object):
    """
    Pipeline to check if image is present in the scraped product
    If not then remove that product from the process
        :param object:
    """

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """
            :param self:
            :param item:
            :param spider:
        """
        if not item['images']:
            spider.logger.error('Images not found', {'item': item})
            raise DropItem

        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `images` field to be populated, the item has to go through the images pipeline.

This means the images pipeline has to be used before your checking one.
To achieve this, give the images pipeline the higher priority (lower order) in your settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 100,
    'scraper.pipelines.ImageCheckPipeline': 200,
}
```

Also, to avoid `KeyError`, you will have to rewrite your code like so (checking for the existence of a key, instead of its value):

```
if 'images' not in item:
    spider.logger.error('Images not found', {'item': item})
    raise DropItem
```

Comment: It gives the same result with your settings. If i use `IMAGES_STORE = /some/folder` everything works

Comment: ok I see, there was a warning `missing boto or boto library` and scrapy was disabling the image pipeline. ```pip install boto``` has to be there for aws image upload.